# Data type similar to timestamp for saving username string in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a data type similar to timestamp but where input can be any string (for example username) that only updates if another column in the row has been updated? This is for mysql. The thing is that my form has dynamically generated rows and I need to save timestamp and user for each row that has been edited. On server side I recieve all inputs/rows whether they have been changed or not.

This is part of the code that handles form data:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    $ids=$_POST['ids'];
    $glosas=$_POST['glosas'];
    $monedas=$_POST['monedas'];
    $montos=$_POST['montos'];
    $tipos=$_POST['tipos'];
    $estados=$_POST['estados'];
    $fechas=$_POST['fechas'];
    $codigos=$_POST['codigos'];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($ids); ++$i) {

    // Initial query parameter values 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':id_contrato' => $ids[$i],
        ':glosa' => $glosas[$i],
        ':moneda' => $monedas[$i],
        ':monto' => $montos[$i],
        ':tipo' => $tipos[$i],
        ':estado' => $estados[$i],
        ':fecha' => $fechas[$i],
        ':codigo_externo' => $codigos[$i],

    ); 


    $query = " 
        UPDATE contratos 
        SET 
        glosa = :glosa
        , moneda = :moneda 
        , monto = :monto
        , tipo = :tipo
        , estado = :estado
        , fecha = :fecha
        , codigo_externo = :codigo_externo  
    "; 

    $query .= " 
        WHERE 
            id_contrato = :id_contrato
        "; 

    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 

        die("No se pudo guardar: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    }


    $elim_contratos=$_POST['elim_contratos'];
    //eliminar contratos checkeados
    if(!empty($elim_contratos)){
    foreach($elim_contratos as $elim_contrato)   {

    // Initial query parameter values 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':id_contrato' => $elim_contrato, 
    );

        $query="DELETE FROM contratos WHERE id_contrato = :id_contrato";

        try 
    { 
        // Execute the query 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 

        die("No se pudo guardar: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    }
    }
```

And this is my table structure in mysql or mariaDB:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `contratos`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contratos` (
  `id_contrato` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `glosa` varchar(140) NOT NULL,
  `moneda` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UF',
  `monto` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `codigo_externo` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Por Definir',
  `last_save` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `saved_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_contrato`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1015 ;
```

The user name is saved in a $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your script that handles the form data? This can be achieved in multiple ways, but depends on your database backend and your data handling.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a [**`timestamp`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) field that is updated each time any column in the row is updated / modified :

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  timestamp_modified timestamp 
       NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
       ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  first_name varchar(50), 
  last_name varchar(50)
  ...etc
)
```

`timestamp_modified` will per default hold the creation time. If the row is modified, the timestamp is updated accordingly.

---

Update. As per comment :

> What I need is for the 'saved_by' column to save the user name when
>   one of the other columns in the row are updated. The user name is in a
>   $_SESSION variable. I suppose one way to do it is check the values in
>   the database before updating an change the query accordingly. I just
>   wanted to know if I can avoid the addional select query by doing it
>   directly in the database.

You could use [**`rowCount`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to skip the additional select.  If nothing is updated `rowCount` will be 0.

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
if ($stmt.rowCount()>0) {
    //update saved_by with the $_SESSION variable
}
```

Comment: What I need is for the 'saved_by' column to save the user name when one of the other columns in the row are updated. The user name is in a $_SESSION variable. 

I suppose one way to do it is check the values in the database before updating an change the query accordingly. I just wanted to know if I can avoid the addional select query by doing it directly in the database.